# Matlab: Avoid for-loops for bayer-pattern demosaicing

Tags: matlab

I implemented a bayer demosaicing and thats works so far, but it is quite slow. I am novice to matlab and figured already that for-loops are usually a bad way of doing things.

That is my algorithim in pseudo-code, can anyone give me a hint how to matlabize it a bit more?

```
pic = zero(width, height, 3)
for i=1:Width
   for j=1:Height
       if isbluevalue(i, j)
          pic(i,j) = getOtherTwoValues(...)
       if isredvalue(i,j)
          //do accordingly
       if isgreenvalue(i,j)
          //do accordingly
 end
end
```

Is there a way to get rid of the for-loops?

Answer (score 3):

There is a built-in function in Matlab that does Bayer demosaicing.

```
 RGB = demosaic(I, sensorAlignment);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do what you want with Matlab's *logical indexing*.  For example, you might write

```
pic(isbluevalue(pic)) = getOtherTwoValues(...)
```

Note that this only works if your function `isbluevalue()` works on the elements of pic, rather than the numbers `i` and `j`.

If this doesn't help, explain your needs a little more fully.